# Understanding Lang's Chapter 6 Theorem 9.1

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

For the past week, I've been trying to dissect and make rigorous my understanding of Lang's theorem, which says that:

> Theorem 9.1 Let $k$ be a field and n an integer $\geq$ 2. Let $a \in k, a \neq 0.$ Assume that for all prime numbers $p$ such that $p \mid n$ we have that $a \notin k^p,$ and if $4 \mid n$ then $a \notin -4k^4.$ Then $X^n - a$ is irreducible in $k[x].$

What follows is a portion of Lang's proof. I cut the argument off where my understanding broke down.

> Our first assumption means that $a$ is not a $p$-th power in $k.$ We shall reduce our theorem to the case when $n$ is a prime power, by induction. 
>   Write $n = p^rm$ with $p$ prime to $m,$ and $p$ odd. Let
>
> $$x^m - a = \prod^m_{v = 1}(x - \alpha_v)$$
>
> be the factorization of $x^m - a$ into linear factors, and say $\alpha
> > = \alpha_1$. Substituting $x^{p^r}$ for $x$ we get
>
> $$x^n - a = x^{p^rm} - a = \prod^m_{v = 1}(x^{p^r} - \alpha_v).$$

So far, there is not much to comment on about Lang's set up. His preliminary work is quite straight forward.

> We may assume inductively that $x^m - a$ is irreducible in $k[x].$ We
>   contend that $\alpha$ is not a $p$-th power in $k(\alpha).$ Otherwise,
>   $\alpha = \beta^p, \beta \in k(\alpha).$ Let $N$ be the norm from
>   $k(\alpha)$ to $k$ then
>
> $$-a = (-1)^mN(\alpha) = (-1)^mN(\beta^p) = (-1)^mN(\beta)^p.$$

This is where Lang begins to lose me. I understand his field Norm argument, as it follows from substitution and the realization of the field Norm as the product of Galois conjugates. And here $-a$ coincides with this product, hence this equality follows. But I don't see why Lang begins to invoke induction here. If someone could explain how this helps us, I would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 1):

We're inducting on the number of distinct prime powers dividing $n$, in order to reduce to the case that there's exactly one prime power dividing $n$, i.e. that $n$ is itself a prime power. That case is dealt with in the part of the proof below where you're copying (starting "We now suppose that $n = p^r$ is a prime power.")

Since we're inducting (and we're spotting the base case, for now), if we write $n = p^rm$ with $m$ coprime to $p$, then $m$ has fewer prime power factors than $n$, so we may assume the theorem is already proven for $m$, that is, that $x^m - a$ is irreducible. We need this assumption because we are trying to work in the *field* $k(\alpha)$, but we would not know this was a field if we didn't know $x^m - a$ was irreducible over $k$. We are going to need that it's a field, because the next step in the argument is to prove that $x^{p^r} - a$ is irreducible over $k(\alpha)$ (which again will follow becuase we're spotting the base case) and use the multiplicativity of degrees of field extensions to get that $x^m - a$ was irreducible over the base.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I was very confused since it was not clear to me what we were inducting over.

Also, what do you mean by "spotting the base case," I am afraid I am not familiar with that terminology.

Comment: @Josabanks sorry, not math terminology, but slang English -- "spotting" in this context means "granting" or "assuming for now."

Comment: let me make sure I understand your logic, so we want to induct over the number of distinct prime powers dividing $n.$ I still don't think I see why induction will help us reduce the case, to just 1 prime. I've only ever encountered induction when we want to generalize a claim. Secondly, I don't think I understand what the base case is here. Is it showing $x^{p^r} - a$ is irreducible? Thirdly, in the paragraph following where I left off, is this Lang's way of completing the argument? He assumes that the theorem for prime powers and then shows how you can finish it.

Comment: @Josabanks right. The base case is showing $x^{p^r} - a$ is irreducible (for any $p$ and $r$). The reason it will help us reduce is actually pretty intricate -- it's because at one point he needs to use a fact about multiplicativity of degrees of field extensions, and without the base case he doesn't know an auxiliary field he's constructed is in fact a field. His induction proof is "backwards" from the normal one -- he does the inductive step first, and then the base case! If you're annoyed with his writing right now, try skipping ahead and reading the base case first.

Comment: So let me see if I understand the simple case when the field characteristic is $p.$ Our base case is proving $x^p - a$ is irreducible, but this follows from Freshman's Dream plus our field norm argument. Now we can assume inductively that $x^{p^{r-1}} - \alpha$ is irreducible. I see that $x^{p^r} - a$ is equal to our inductive polynomial raised to the $p$-th power, but I am not sure why we can conclude that this guarantees it is irreducible. Is this just because we know that each $\alpha$ is not in the field?